# How to Create Instagram liked image cropping using React Native?

Tags: react-native, image-processing, crop

How do you make an image cropper that allows users to freely crop the image with its aspect ratio between 1:1 and 4:3?

What Instagram does is when you are making a post and switch to the 4:3 mode, you can pinch and zoom to increase the ratio from 3:4 to up to 1:1 and they crop out the part outside the preview box.

I've tried existing packages like `react-native-image-crop-crop-tools` and `react-native-image-crop-picker` and none of them allows free cropping within a ratio range. The best they can do it to let you choose some preset ratios and they can crop the image.

Any help?

Answer (score 0):

At the link bellow you can see an example application which allows you to cut an image like the instagram image cropper
[link](https://www.npmjs.com/package/react-native-instagram-like-image-cropper)